# How to cap the number of duplicates values in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with highly redundant data thus I would like to copy this data frame to a new data frame, setting a maximum redundancy of my indexed column.

In the following example, "pop" is my indexed column; in my new dataframe I would like to set a maximum redundancy of 2:

```
data = {"state":["Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Nevada","Nevada"],
'year' : [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],'pop' : ["pop1", "pop1","pop1","pop2","pop2"]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
frame = frame.set_index('pop')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `groupby` together with `head(n)` to return the first `n` rows of each group:

```
frame.groupby('pop').head(2)
Out[32]: 
    pop   state  year
0  pop1    Ohio  2000
1  pop1    Ohio  2001
3  pop2  Nevada  2001
4  pop2  Nevada  2002
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how Wes McKinney implements [filtering duplicates](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/filtering-out-duplicate-dataframe-rows/). A drop_duplicates method is currently supported on the dataframe object, but it will take the groupby approach to implement exactly what you want.